# SEO Tips for new Website

Tags: seo

I am no expert in SEO but I do know how it works and stuff.

What I would like to know is what steps do YOU guys take when starting a new SEO project. Like from beginning to end.

Also I would like to rent/buy links. Can someone please point me to the right direction on doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow! This is a huge topic. It is not simple at all. Let's start with what you do know and perhaps I can add some points that can help.

Comment: Well I know content importance, keywords, backlinking, social media importance. Maybe I don't know much, so yes I need some pointers. Specially on link building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. Very short answer. Sorta.

Keyword Research:
Oddly, the simplist methods are the best. I use the Google Ajax search text box a lot. I also use Google Trends which can give excellent clues. It amazes me how many people fail to use Google Trends or to pay much attention to it. I also use:

http://www.noblesamurai.com/ and 
http://www.link-assistant.com/

Next I organize my content into theme pyramids... a fancy way to organize stuff. Example: Cookware, then pots, pans, utensils, etc., then frying pans, cast iron pans. etc. I then decide (assuming a static site for a moment) what directories using the theme pyramid makes sense and use my most important keywords per theme to name them. Then I put the appropriate content pages into the directories using the most important keywords per page to name them. Each page should have it's own set of keywords though some may overlap a bit. When done, I use my keywords per theme and page and create some sort of organization for reference. I use notepad.

From there, I edit each page and apply my keywords to the title, description, h1 and h2 tags, first paragraph, and first 200k of content following the Headline Read Order outlined below.

Title Tag: About 60 characters with your most important keywords for the page.
Description Meta-Tag: About 150 character with the same keywords as in the title but with more keywords that support your work.
URL:
__Domain Name: Should contain two or three of your sites most important keywords if possible.
__Directory / Page Title: The same most important keywords you used in your title.
Inbound Link: Each link should vary somewhat as much as possible. Consistantly use your most important keywords but vary your lessor important supporting keywords.
Header Tag: Your first HTML tag within the body should be the H1 tag if possible. It should mirror the title closely though should also vary somewhat.
First Paragraph: Your first paragraph should as naturally as possible use all of your most important keywords and secondary supporting keywords.

Then I take my most important keywords and content clusters (topic or group of topics) and create navigation buttons to my most important work. It may be that I have to create landing pages in between and link to pages from there. Just make sure you are following your keyword plan.

Then I create breadcrumbs per page per content cluster and cross link pages as much as I can without getting silly as [you know...].

Then I create a sitemap and make sure Google and Bing know about them. You can add an entry to your robots.txt file or create accounts on Google or Bing. Robots.txt may be easier and faster plus Yandex and other search engines can find it.

Then I create some inbound links where I can. I prefer organic as much as possible, however, if your site is good, then DMOZ.org and other directories can help people find your content.

Do not pay for links or rent them or enter into any other link scheme. If you have friends and it makes sense for them to link to your site, then buy them a six-pack.

I do not do the social thing, however, it is a good thing. Twitter seems like a good idea only if you have something to say often enough. Do not create an account and then tweet only a few times. If you have an e-mail list, then notify your contacts about the site. Do not use a bulk e-mail scheme or e-mail strangers. I am not a Facebook fan. However, if you use LinkedIn or Google+ then that is another resource.

That alone should keep you busy for a while. Meanwhile, I suggest reading a lot. My site has some stuff. I like MOZ and it may be a better resource for a beginner. My site gets into marketing a lot and you may go cross-eyed. I have much more stuff to post soon.

Let me know your progress. I can add more as you go.

Good Luck!

Comment: Sorry. My headline read order should have been separate lines. Sorta confusing otherwise.